# Определить в каких случаях мы имеем с нарушением слогового принципа графики, а каких с отклонением от него

Tags: морфология

Определить в каких случаях мы имеем с нарушением слогового принципа графики, а каких с отклонением от него: Принтер, циркуль, палач, фойс, бартер, цельный, шеф, медальон, модель, шествовать, плющом, модный, расческа. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Что вас конкретно интересует - какие слова можно разделить на слоги?

Comment: Серж, слоговой принцип графики - это новая  идея, которую изобрели наши лингвисты, чтобы "мучить" школьников и студентов. Слоговой принцип графики заключается в том, что в определённых случаях в качестве единицы письма выступает не буква, а слог, сочетание согласной и гласной. Слоговой принцип применяется в обозначении парных по твёрдости-мягкости согласных и т.д. Короче говоря, это обычные правила русского письма в части обозначения мягкости согласных или звука Й, которые изучаются в начальной школе. Но если, к примеру,  мы пишем "шёл" или "бульон, йод", то "нарушаем" это правило и т.д.

Comment: А-а, не слышал. Спасибо. согласен. Лишний раз засоряют голову учащимся.

Comment: Вообще-то это больше напоминает домашнее задание. ilko92, вы дайте свой вариант, мы проверим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Только в качестве версии**

**Нарушения**

принтЕр, цИркуль,  бартЕр, цЕльный, шЕф,  модЕль, шЕствовать, плющОм - после твердого согласного пишется Е, И, а не Э, Ы; после мягкого пишется О, а не Ё.

**Отклонения**:  медальон, вместо Ё пишется ЬО, палач - нет мягкого знака после мягкого согласного Ч.

Comment: Ой, спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Нарушения слогового принципа создаются орфографией и наблюдаются в сфере обозначения йота, когда написание не соответствует прочтению:

1) вместо ё, полагающегося по слоговому принципу, фактически пишется буквосочетание йо: йод,  йот,йотированный, йоги,

2) вместо ё после ь фактически пишется о: батальон, бульон, медальон, павильон, почтальон, гильотина;

3) вместо букв типа я пишутся сочетания этих букв с предшествующим й — йе (буква ё здесь не представлена):йеменский, фейерверк, фойе; йя — Майя, Гойя и т.п.

Написания, содержащие нарушения слогового принципа, устанавливаются орфографией в словарном порядке.
У Вас это **фойе, медальон,**

Еще одним нарушением  слогового принципа (его можно, пожалуй, назвать 
временным) является написание заимствованных слов с буквой е после твердых согласных: дельта — [дэ], кашне — [нэ], пенсне — [нэ], фонема, отель,тембр и т.п. Такое написание установлено потому, что твердые согласные в заимствованных словах постепенно, по мере обрусения, заменяются соответствующими мягкими согласными, например: тема, газета, шинель, портфель и т.п. Написания по произношению с э, во-первых, задержали бы этот в целом прогрессивный процесс, а во-вторых, в дальнейшем пришли бы в противоречие с новым произношением; потребовалось бы их изменение. Можно сказать поэтому, что написание с е здесь установлено как бы авансом, а само нарушение принципа лишь временное.
У Вас это  **Принтер, бартер, модель**

Отступления - это те случаи нарушения слогового принципа русской графики, когда он может быть соблюден, однако не соблюдается.

Отступления от правил слогового принципа графики, определяющих соотношение соседних букв в слове, наблюдаются в области употребления гласных букв, мягкого знака и "буквы пробела" после шипящих и ц.
Звуки [ч, щ] — мягкие, а [ж, ш, ц] — твердые, поэтому, казалось бы, по предписаниям слогового принципа после букв, обозначающих эти звуки, гласные буквы, а также знаки мягкости и твердости должны были бы быть дифференцированы: после ч, щ следовало бы писать гласные буквы типа я, а на конце слов — мягкий знак; после ж, ш, ц — гласные типа а, а конец слов оставлять без мягкого знака.

Фактически же после всех этих букв — и после ч, щ, и после ж, ш, ц — пишутся то гласные типа а (а, у, о, пробел, а после ц еще и ы), то гласные типа я (е, и, иногда ю, а после шипящих, но не после ц, еще ё и ь); не пишется только буква э. Например:

ч: час, чудо, плечо и челка, честь, чан, врач и ночь;

щ: пощада, щука, плащом и щетка, щебень, щи, плащ и помощь;

ж: жар, жук и жюри, поджог (сущ.) и поджег (гл.), жест, жить, еж, рожь;

ш: шаг, шум и брошюра, хорошо и шел, шест, шило, шалаш и глушь;

ц: цапля, цугом, письмецо, цель, цыган и цирк, огурец.

У Вас это **палач, цельный, шеф,  шествовать, плющом**

**Модный, расчёска**- нарушений и отклонений не вижу.

Comment: А вообще, смотрите в свои лекции, потому что далеко не все авторы используют такие термины, многие  не разделяют отступления и нарушения, другие говорят о 2 типах отступлений: нарушения и ограничения. Мы можем оказать Вам медвежью услугу.

Comment: Вообще говоря, если терминов не знать, а исходить только из логики, то НАРУШЕНИЕ должно быть связано с искажением информации, например: после твердого согласного  написаны буквы Е, И, Ё, то есть не соблюдено основное правило твердая пара - мягкая пара. А отклонение, как и отступление, похоже на дополнительное правило, например: сочетание ЙО передается буквой Ё, но в частном случае можно обозначить двумя буквами.

Comment: Но это логика, которая должна присутствовать даже в таких "упражнениях" наших авторов, как слоговой принцип письма.  А самая медвежья услуга, которую можно оказать ученику, - это отучить его думать, сравнивать, анализировать и давать собственную оценку  любой информации. В этом случае различные решения задачи могут быть полезнее, чем угаданный  (соответствующий мнению автора) "правильный" ответ.

Comment: Это всё так, но автору хотелось бы помощи в реальном задании, ему наши "умствования" логические ни к чему, а вот термины надо бы знать. А логика может быть разная. Отступление, отклонение от нормы по логике - всё это нарушения нормы. Это логика общая. В основном все учёные так и используют эти слова как синонимы, но в последнее время отдельные авторы стали разграничивать, так что нужно точно знать, что они имеют в виду под этими терминами.